# Enabling default Datatables Search functionality in NOPCommerce DataTablesModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I am on NOPCommerce 4.50 and I am trying to use Datatables' default search functionality in one of my child datatables in NOPCommerce.

I want to enable search for this table in Specification Attributes;

```
                    {
                    Name = "specificationattributes-grid",
                    UrlRead = new DataUrl("SpecificationAttributeList", "SpecificationAttribute", null),
                    IsChildTable = true,
                    Length = Model.PageSize,
                    LengthMenu = Model.AvailablePageSizes,
                    Filters = new List<FilterParameter>
                    {
                    new FilterParameter(nameof(SpecificationAttributeModel.SpecificationAttributeGroupId), nameof(SpecificationAttributeGroupModel.Id), true)
                    },
                    ColumnCollection = new List<ColumnProperty>
                    {
                    new ColumnProperty(nameof(SpecificationAttributeModel.Id))
                    {
                    IsMasterCheckBox = true,
                    Render = new RenderCheckBox("checkbox_specificationattributes"),
                    ClassName =  NopColumnClassDefaults.CenterAll,
                    Width = "50"
                    },
                    new ColumnProperty(nameof(SpecificationAttributeModel.Name))
                    {
                    Title = T("Admin.Catalog.Attributes.SpecificationAttributes.SpecificationAttribute.Fields.Name").Text,
                    Width = "300",
                    Searchable = true
                    },
                    new ColumnProperty(nameof(SpecificationAttributeModel.DisplayOrder))
                    {
                    Title = T("Admin.Catalog.Attributes.SpecificationAttributes.SpecificationAttribute.Fields.DisplayOrder").Text,
                    Width = "150",
                    ClassName =  NopColumnClassDefaults.CenterAll
                    },
                    new ColumnProperty(nameof(SpecificationAttributeModel.Id))
                    {
                    Title = T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text,
                    Width = "50",
                    ClassName = NopColumnClassDefaults.Button,
                    Render = new RenderButtonEdit(new DataUrl("EditSpecificationAttribute"))
                    }
                    }
                    }
```

Although I have done `Searchable = true` in the column that I want to make searchable, the search textbox doesnot seem to appear in the datatable. Datatables' paging functionalities are working fine though.

Can anyone help me out??

Comment: you got the solution ?

Comment: No, not till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't enable search option because it's custom ajax Datatable implemented. And new data are loading from system on pagination change. While default datatable js load all data at a time and render in dom and searching data from dom.